# Groupby like Python's itertools.groupby

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Python I'm able to group consecutive elements with the same key by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> items = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 7), (1, 5), (1, 4)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(key for key,it in itertools.groupby(items, lambda tup: tup[0]))
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Scala has `groupBy` as well, but it produces different result - a map pointing from key to all the values found in the iterable with the specified key (not the consecutive runs with the same key):

```
scala> val items = List((1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 7), (1, 5), (1, 4))
items: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,5), (1,3), (2,9), (3,7), (1,5), (1,4))

scala> items.groupBy {case (key, value) => key}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(2 -> List((2,9)), 1 -> List((1,2), (1,5), (1,3), (1,5), (1,4)), 3 -> List((3,7)))
```

What is the most eloquent way of achieving the same as with Python `itertools.groupby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to throw out sequential duplicates, you can do something like this:

```
def unchain[A](items: Seq[A]) = if (items.isEmpty) items else {
  items.head +: (items zip items.drop(1)).collect{ case (l,r) if r != l => r }
}
```

That is, just compare the list to a version of itself shifted by one place, and only keep the items which are different.  It's easy to add a `(same: (a1: A, a2: A) => Boolean)` parameter to the method and use `!same(l,r)` if you want custom behavior for what counts as the same (e.g. do it just by key).

If you want to keep the duplicates, you can use Scala's `groupBy` to get a very compact (but inefficient) solution:

```
def groupSequential(items: Seq[A])(same: (a1: A, a2: A) => Boolean) = {
  val ns = (items zip items.drop(1)).
    scanLeft(0){ (n,cc) => if (same(cc._1, cc._2)) n+1 else n }
  (ns zip items).groupBy(_._1).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
}
```

Comment: What if I like to return last of each group (not the first ones as in your example)?

Comment: @ovgolovin - `collect{ case (l,r) if r != l => l }` and then `:+ items.last` instead of taking the head.

Answer (score 2):

Using `List.span`, like this

```
def keyMultiSpan(l: List[(Int,Int)]): List[List[(Int,Int)]] = l match {

  case Nil => List()
  case h :: t =>
    val ms = l.span(_._1 == h._1)
    ms._1 :: keyMultiSpan(ms._2)
}
```

Hence let

```
val items = List((1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 7), (1, 5), (1, 4))
```

and so

```
keyMultiSpan(items).map { _.head._1 }
res: List(1, 2, 3, 1)
```

**Update**

A more readable syntax, as suggested by @Paul, an implicit class for possibly neater usage, and type parameterisation for generality,

```
implicit class RichSpan[A,B](val l: List[(A,B)]) extends AnyVal {

  def keyMultiSpan(): List[List[(A,B)]] = l match {

      case Nil => List()
      case h :: t =>
        val (f, r) = l.span(_._1 == h._1)
        f :: r.keyMultiSpan()
  }
}
```

Thus, use it as follows,

```
items.keyMultiSpan.map { _.head._1 }
res: List(1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Comment: mildly cleaner as `val (f, r) = l.span([...]); f::keyMultiSpan(r)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
val items = List((1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 7), (1, 5), (1, 4))
val res = compress(items.map(_._1))

/** Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements **/
def compress[T](l : List[T]) : List[T] = l match {
  case head :: next :: tail if (head == next) => compress(next :: tail)
  case head :: tail => head :: compress(tail)
  case Nil => List()
}

/** Tail recursive version **/
def compress[T](input: List[T]): List[T] = {
  def comp(remaining: List[T], l: List[T], last: Any): List[T] = {
    remaining match {
      case Nil => l
      case head :: tail if head == last => comp(tail, l, head)
      case head :: tail => comp(tail, head :: l, head)
    }
  }
  comp(input, Nil, Nil).reverse
}
```

Where `compress` is the solution of one of the [99 Problems in Scala](http://99problemsinscala.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/p08-eliminate-consecutive-duplicates-of-list-elements/).

Comment: The `head :: compress(tail)` expression makes `compress` not tail-recursive - this will blow the stack.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is just an elegant answer that works for not too big inputs

Comment: I added a tail rec version

Answer (score 1):

Here is a succinct but inefficient solution:

```
def pythonGroupBy[T, U](items: Seq[T])(f: T => U): List[List[T]] = {
  items.foldLeft(List[List[T]]()) {
    case (Nil, x) => List(List(x))
    case (g :: gs, x) if f(g.head) == f(x) => (x :: g) :: gs
    case (gs, x) => List(x) :: gs
  }.map(_.reverse).reverse
}
```

And here is a better one, that only invokes `f` on each element once:

```
def pythonGroupBy2[T, U](items: Seq[T])(f: T => U): List[List[T]] = {
  if (items.isEmpty)
    List(List())
  else {
    val state = (List(List(items.head)), f(items.head))
    items.tail.foldLeft(state) { (state, x) =>
      val groupByX = f(x)
      state match {
        case (g :: gs, groupBy) if groupBy == groupByX => ((x :: g) :: gs, groupBy)
        case (gs, _) => (List(x) :: gs, groupByX)
      }
    }._1.map(_.reverse).reverse
  }
}
```

Both solutions fold over `items`, building up a list of groups as they go. `pythonGroupBy2` also keeps track of the value of `f` for the current group. At the end, we have to reverse each group and the list of groups in order to get the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

hmm couldn't find something out of the box but this will do it

```
def groupz[T](list:List[T]):List[T] = {
      list match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case x::Nil => List(x)
      case x::xs if (x == xs.head) => groupz(xs)
      case x::xs => x::groupz(xs)
      }}

//now let's add this functionality to List class 
 implicit def addPythonicGroupToList[T](list:List[T]) = new {def pythonGroup = groupz(list)}
```

**and now you can do:**

```
val items = List((1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 7), (1, 5), (1, 4))
items.map(_._1).pythonGroup
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that I used for a problem I stumbled on at work. In this case I didn't care too much about space, so did not worry about efficient iterators. Used an ArrayBuffer to accumulate the results.

(Don't use this with enormous amounts of data.)

## Sequential GroupBy

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Main {

  /** Returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. */
  def sequentialGroupBy[A, K](items: Seq[A], f: A => K): ArrayBuffer[(K, ArrayBuffer[A])] = {
    val result = ArrayBuffer[(K, ArrayBuffer[A])]()
  
    if (items.nonEmpty) {
      // Iterate, keeping track of when the key changes value.
      var bufKey: K = f(items.head)
      var buf: ArrayBuffer[A] = ArrayBuffer()
  
      for (elem <- items) {
        val key = f(elem)
  
        if (key == bufKey) {
          buf += elem
        } else {
          val group: (K, ArrayBuffer[A]) = (bufKey, buf)
          result += group
          bufKey = key
          buf = ArrayBuffer(elem)
        }
      }
  
      // Append last group.
      val group: (K, ArrayBuffer[A]) = (bufKey, buf)
      result += group
    }
    result
  }
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("\nExample 1:")
    sequentialGroupBy[Int, Int](
      Seq(1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 16), 
      x => x % 2
    ).foreach(println)

    println("\nExample 2:")
    sequentialGroupBy[String, Boolean](
      Seq("pi", "nu", "rho", "alpha", "xi"), 
      x => x.length > 2
    ).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Running the above code results in the following:

```
Example 1:
(1,ArrayBuffer(1))
(0,ArrayBuffer(4))
(1,ArrayBuffer(5, 7, 9))
(0,ArrayBuffer(8, 16))

Example 2:
(false,ArrayBuffer(pi, nu))
(true,ArrayBuffer(rho, alpha))
(false,ArrayBuffer(xi))
```